# How To Create a Vector Using Numpy Similar To MATLAB syntax of: -5:0.01:5

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

using MATLAB the following code returns a vector starting from -5 to 5 with elements that has 0.01 difference:

```
x = -5:0.01:5;
```

what is the equivalent syntax using `numpy`

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace

Comment: @schwobaseggl `linspace` takes the number of points not the `difference`

Comment: @Yacola The `arange` docs warn against using it with float steps and recommend `linspace`.

Comment: @yekanchi True, one can directly be calculated form the other, so this shouldn't be a big issue. E.g. `points = int((stop - start) / step) + 1` or sth like tht

Comment: Did you try: `np.arange(-5, 5, .01)`?  That's most direct equivalent, though its handling of the end value is different.  The similarity between MATLAB's `linspace` and `np.linspace` is closer.

Answer (score 1):

This would need an explicit conversion, and probably the intention was to use the limits? - something like:

```
x = np.linspace(-5,5,int((5-(-5))/.01)+1)
```

or in general

```
x = np.linspace(minlimit, maxlimit, int((maxlimit-minlimit)/step)+1)
```

An alternative is to use numpy arange, and, *supposing the range is an exact multiple of the step size*, add the step to the second argument of arange:

```
x = np.arange(-5, 5 + .01, 0.01)
```

or in general:

```
x = np.arange(minlimit, maxlimit+step, step)
```

I am not sure how robust this is against jitter due to limited resolution of floating point values.

Comment: Both these approaches are invariably going to suffer from rounding errors (still, +1). Here are some ideas for how to build a more robust solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377234/how-does-matlabs-colon-operator-work

Answer (score 0):

based on the comments this was convenient for me:

```
 x = np.linspace(-5,5,1/0.01)
```