# I want to stop the code when x is equal to 1

Tags: octave, numerical-analysis

I used Octave to write this code.

```
x=0.0;   
while (x~=1.0)
  x=x+0.1;
  fprintf('x=%20.18f\n',x)
  pause
endwhile
```

I want to stop the code when `x` is equal to `1`.
So, I put some code like this

```
x=0.0;   
while (x~=1.0)
   x=x+0.1;
   fprintf('x=%20.18f\n',x)
   if abs(x-1)<(eps/2),
      print(x)
   endif
   pause
endwhile
```

But it did not work, and show numbers infinitely. How can I write a code to stop this code when `x` is equal to `1`?

Answer (score 3):

When you add:

```
x = 0.0;
x = x + 0.1;
```

You can end up with `x = 0.100000000000000006` for example due to numerical precision so the `while` will never exit since it's always going to be different than `1`.

You can use the less than `<` operator to stop the loop when `x` is equal to `1`:

```
x=0.0;   
while (x < 1.0)
   x=x+0.1;
   fprintf('x=%20.18f\n',x)
   if abs(x-1)<(eps/2),
      print(x)
   endif
   pause
endwhile
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try using an iterator `k` for `while` loop, rather than `x` itself, i.e.,

```
k = 0;
x = 0.0;   
while (k~=round(1.0/0.1))
  k += 1;
  x += 0.1;
  fprintf('x=%20.18f\n',x);
endwhile
```

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your feedback. Yes, I tried it and found that `1.0/0.1` is identical to `10`. Anyway, to play it safe, maybe `round(1.0/0.1)` would be better.

Comment: Anyway your advice here is the best, always use an integer as a loop variable. If you know the number of iterations it’s easier: `for x=0:0.1:1`, which is [designed to reach 1 at the end if x gets sufficiently close](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49377234/7328782).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, agree, `for` should be a better option if the number of iterations is known.