# Difference of linspace and colon notation is giving non-zero elements

Tags: octave

My problem is the following: Write the colon notation `0 : 0.2 : 10` in `linspace` function and write a command such that the difference of the two is seem to be 0.

I try the following code:

```matlab
A = 0 : 0.2 : 10
B = linspace(0, 10, 51)
A - B
```

However, it is giving the following output

```
ans =

 Columns 1 through 6:
0            0            0            0            0            0

 Columns 7 through 12:
0            0            0            0            0            0

 Columns 13 through 18:
0            0            0            0            0            0

 Columns 19 through 24:
0            0            0            0            0            0

 Columns 25 through 30:
0            0   8.8818e-16   8.8818e-16   8.8818e-16   8.8818e-16

 Columns 31 through 36:
0   8.8818e-16            0   8.8818e-16   8.8818e-16            0

 Columns 37 through 42:
8.8818e-16            0   8.8818e-16   8.8818e-16            0   1.7764e-15

 Columns 43 through 48:
0            0            0            0   1.7764e-15            0

 Columns 49 through 51:
1.7764e-15            0            0
```

The non-zero elements are bugging me. I think I nailed the `linspace` part. How do I form a command so that the difference is seen as zero? I need some hints. Please try to hint a command as elementary as possible without using advanced tools!

Comment: What does `[0:50]/5` give? I don't think you'll get the two to ever *completely* agree if they use different methods to calculate the intervening values. Your values are really close to epsilon (10^-15 or 10^-16 in this case).

Comment: I think the trick is to do proper floating-point comparisons. I think this exercise is meant to show you that floating-point numbers are approximations. You cannot write 0.2 exactly in binary. Computing the same thing in different ways leads to different rounding errors. When comparing floating-point numbers, always use a tolerance. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/686439/7328782

Comment: Also, this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/590851/4598449

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand what is going on, instead of trying to understand the concepts of "limited binary precision", "numbers not exactly representable in binary", consider the equivalent situation in the context of 'decimal precision' and 'numbers not exactly representable in decimal' instead. For convenience, let's consider the simpler problem where:

```
A = 0 : 1/6 : 1
B = linspace( 0, 1, 7 )
```

and let's assume that our CPU is precise up to 4 significant digits.

With regards to A; Here, we note that 1/6 is not directly representable in decimal. Our decimal CPU will therefore convert this to the nearest decimal representation, i.e. 0.1667. Thus the range will become:

```
  0,
  0      + 0.1667 = 0.1667
  0.1667 + 0.1667 = 0.3334
  0.3334 + 0.1667 = 0.5001
  0.5001 + 0.1667 = 0.6668
  0.6668 + 0.1667 = 0.8335
  0.8335 + 0.1667 = 1.0002
```

With regards to B: internally, the linspace algorithm will try to perform the following calculations:

```
B = 
     0/6 = 0.0000
     1/6 = 0.1667
     2/6 = 0.3333
     3/6 = 0.5000
     4/6 = 0.6667
     5/6 = 0.8333
     6/6 = 1.0000
```

Therefore, in a decimal system with a 4-significant digit precision:

```
A-B = 
      0
      0
      0.0001
      0.0001
      0.0001
      0.0002
      0.0002
```

A similar situation happens in binary; the value 0.2 is not 'exactly 'representable in binary, therefore it is approximated. In the 'range', it is added repeatedly. In the 'linspace', divisions take place internally, and the output is approximated if not exactly divisible by 2.

So your question, "how can I get A-B to be exactly 0" is not a matter of choosing a 'better function'. It's a matter of getting a theoretical computer with infinite precision to do your calculation.

Therefore, you're asking the wrong question. The right question is, are these two outputs identically zero given some degree of tolerance that takes machine precision into account? And how much tolerance is acceptable?

One way to answer this question is via the `assert` function, together with the `eps` function which returns the machine precision, to see if two variables are equal within some tolerance relative to `eps`:

```
try  ; assert( A, B, eps ), disp('All elements are equal for the given tolerance')
catch; disp('Elements were not equal for the given tolerance')
end_try_catch
# Elements were not equal for the given tolerance

try  ; assert( A, B, 10*eps ), disp('All elements are equal for the given tolerance')
catch; disp('Elements were not equal for the given tolerance')
end_try_catch
# All elements are equal for the given tolerance
```

On my machine, eps=2e-16. Therefore A-B is zero, within a tolerance of 2e-15. Whether or not this is acceptable depends entirely on you and the nature of your problem. But machine precision is an inherent limitation of computers, and one must be aware that it exists and how it affects your interpretation of calculations.

Comment: Maybe the tolerance should be `eps(0.2)`? Anyway, I wanted to point to [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49377234/7328782), which details how `0 : 1/6 : 1` is computed and explains why the last value in the result is exactly 1, not slightly larger.

Comment: Thanks @Cris! Interesting read! I admit I didn't care to look at the implementation of the colon operator for this explanation, it was meant to be more pedagogical than anything. Though I _did_ secretly suspect octave/matlab probably does something else under the hood to make sure the end-boundary is included, as I've never seen it omitted when trying out a range. Good to know the reason for this :)