Incrementing an extra step in MATLAB loop yields incorrect values?
I'm encountering some very weird behaviour in some MATLAB code I've written, and can't quite tell why. If I increment the loop from 0.01 in steps of 0.01 to 0.09, all values are correct. However, if I step from 0.01:0.10, a single extra step, MOST values are correct but some previous ones get absolutely messed up. The weird thing is that the loop doesn't depend on any previous values, each iteration is 'fresh' so I'm kind of perplexed why this is happening. Any idea? I should also note that if I run the problem values independently out of the loop, the correct answer is obtained. MWE under images...

MWE:
    v = [0.5];
    pv = 0.01:0.01:0.1;  %broken version..
    n = 1000;
    h = 3.841;
    fp = zeros(size(pv)); % Preallocate to avoid size issues

 for kx = 1:length(pv)
  p = pv(kx); 

% Recalculate functions dependent on 'p'
a = @(y) y;
b = @(x) x;
c = @(x, y) p*n - y;
d = @(x) n*(1 - p) - x;

new = @(x, y) (n.*(a(y).*d(x) - b(x).*c(x, y)).^2) ./ ...
    ((a(y) + b(x)) .* (c(x, y) + d(x)) .* (a(y) + c(x, y)) .* (b(x) + d(x))) - h;

for j = 1:length(v)    
 yp = 0:p*n;
 xp = v(j).*n - yp;    
 f = new(xp,yp);
 fin = find(f<0);
 yv{j} = yp(fin);    

 end

 % Use ndgrid dynamically for all cell elements
  grid_cells = cell(1, numel(yv));
  [grid_cells{:}] = ndgrid(yv{:});

  % Convert grid into combinations matrix
  combinations = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(:), grid_cells, 'UniformOutput', false));

  % Check that each element in the row is less than or equal to the next
  valid_rows = all(diff(combinations, 1, 2) >= 0, 2);

  % Keep only valid combinations
  filtered_combinations = combinations(valid_rows, :);

  i = 1;
  probs = zeros(size(filtered_combinations)); 
  probs(:,1) = hygepdf(filtered_combinations(:,1),n,round(n.*p),round(v(1).*n));

   while i < (length(v))

   remy = round(n.*p - filtered_combinations(:,i));
   yhits = filtered_combinations(:,i+1) - filtered_combinations(:,i);
   npick = round(n.*(v(i+1) - v(i)));
   nrem = round(n.*(1-v(i)));    
   probs(:,i+1) = hygepdf(yhits,nrem,remy,npick);       
   i = i +1;
   end

  full = prod(probs,2); 
  falsepositive = 1 - sum(full)

  % Store results in 'fp' array
  fp(kx) = falsepositive;

  % Explicitly reset variables if needed (avoiding clearvars)
  end


All your loop indices can change (by tiny amounts) when you change the end point. You might find this explanation interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49377234/how-does-the-colon-operator-work-in-matlab -- You should always use integers as loop indices, if you care about reproducibility and precision.

NONE of the decimal values in pv = 0.01:0.01:0.1 can be represented exactly in IEEE double precision. The actual values in pv are approximations to these decimal numbers. You should not expect to get exact decimal results if you do arithmetic with these kinds of double precision values, so you need to adjust your expectations accordingly and modify your code to account for this. This is not weird behavior, it is expected floating point arithmetic behavior in any computer language, not just MATLAB. You might also explore using the linspace( ) function instead of the colon operator.

Less than 10 minutes after posting this I was able to finally detect the source of the weird error: for some reason, and only on certain loop conditions, MATLAB would report a number in the cell yp with some numerical round-off, reporting it as 35.0 for example instead of 35. This would cause the hygepdf to return a null value, because it can only work with integers, hence the screw up. The solution was to use a rounding function on yp, and this line fixed it:
 yv{j} = round(yp(fin));   

I'll leave this up here in case anyone else has similar problems, but cannot explain why it only had those round up errors with certain loop iterations and not with others!
